# json read in c# issue

Tags: c#, json

I am using a function to read from a json file and reaturn a list of class to the UI. My class is

```
 public class UseCase
    {
        public string UseCaseId { get; set;}
        public string UseCaseDescription { get; set;}
    }
```

The function is like this

```
 List<UseCase> usecaseList = new List<UseCase>();
ReadUsecaseContentFronJsonFile1();
         usecaseList = UseCaseList();
```

The UseCaseList() is

```
private List<UseCase> UseCaseList()
        {
            List<UseCase> usecaseList = new List<UseCase>();
            foreach (var value in deserializedData1.Values)
            {
                UseCase objUC = new UseCase();

                objUC.UseCaseId = value.UseCaseId;
                objUC.UseCaseDescription = value.UseCaseDescription;
                usecaseList.Add(objUC);
            }
            return usecaseList;//isSigRequired;
        }

private void ReadUsecaseContentFronJsonFile1()
        {
            deserializedData1 = ReadFromJsonFile1<Dictionary<string, UseCase>>();
        }
```

The function to read from json file is like this

```
 protected static T ReadFromJsonFile1<T>() where T : new()
        {
            TextReader JsonReader = null;
            try
            {
                var filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UsecaseListPath");
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    JsonReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                    var fileContents = JsonReader.ReadToEnd();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContents);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new T();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (JsonReader != null)
                    JsonReader.Close();
            }
        }
```

I am not getting the json file values in (deserializedData1). What could be the issue??

My json file is:

```
{

    "UseCases": {
        "UseCase": [{
            "UseCaseId": "CCS01",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Add Device to  CHF device log"
        }, {
            "UseCaseId": "CCS02",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Remove device from  CHF device log"
        }, {
            "UseCaseId": "CCS03",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Restore CHF Device  Log"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileName = @"c:\temp\test.json";
    var reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
    var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

    var useCases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<UseCase>>>(fileContent);
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
```

Provided your JSON is modified to this (as pointed out in the previous post):

```
{
    "UseCases": [{        
            "UseCaseId": "CCS01",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Add Device to  CHF device log"
        }, {
            "UseCaseId": "CCS02",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Remove device from  CHF device log"
        }, {
            "UseCaseId": "CCS03",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Restore CHF Device  Log"
        }]
}
```

Comment: yes I am getting the list values in useCases. But how to convert it into List<Usecase>???

Answer (score 1):

Look at the beginning of the JSON document:

```
{
    "UseCases": {
        "UseCase": [{
```

It says that you have a root object which contains an object which contains a object which contains a list ;) Or more nicely:

1. You have a root **object**
2. The root object contains a field named "UseCases" which is an **object**.
3. That field "UseCases" contains a property "UseCase" which is a **collection**

Code:

```
// For the root object which contains the "UseCases" field
public class RootObject
{
    public UseCasesContainer UseCases { get; set; }
}

// For the "UsesCases" field, the tricky thing is that 
// it's not a collection but an object
public class UseCasesContainer
{

    // ..which contains a collection field.
    public Collection<UsesCase> UsesCase { get; set; }
}
```

The collection itself contains `UseCase` objects like you specified.

Thus to deserialize it you can use json.net like:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJson);

//don't be fooled by the property name, this is the collection
var allUseCases = rootObject.UseCases.UseCase;
```

If your JSON only should contain use cases you could have created a document without fields:

```
[
        {
            "UseCaseId": "CCS01",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Add Device to  CHF device log"
        }, {
            "UseCaseId": "CCS02",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Remove device from  CHF device log"
        }, {
            "UseCaseId": "CCS03",
            "UseCaseDescription": "Restore CHF Device  Log"
        }
]
```

.. which could just have been deserialized as:

```
var useCases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<UseCase>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see the JSON format is wrong.. replace the json with below

[Click here to view the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaCPs.png)